# Firebase security rule not working on CollectionGroup

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have this security rule code

```
  match /{path=**}/favorited/{userUID} {
  allow create, update, read: if request.auth.uid == userUID;
}
```

And this is the error message I got

> W/Firestore( 6236): (21.3.0) [Firestore]: Listen for Query( collectionGroup=favorited where userUID == abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz and favorite == true order by -updatedAt, -**name**) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}

The Query I used is

```
  Firestore.instance.collectionGroup('favorited')
    .where('userUID', isEqualTo: user.uid)
    .where('favorite', isEqualTo: true)
    .orderBy('updatedAt', descending: true).snapshots()
```

I can't figure out which part of security rule for collectionGroup went wrong.
Query code worked fine when there was no security rule.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Query:

```
Firestore.instance.collectionGroup('favorited')
    .where('userUID', isEqualTo: user.uid)
    .where('favorite', isEqualTo: true)
    .orderBy('updatedAt', descending: true).snapshots()
```

...is looking for any documents (unknown Id's) that have a *field* `{userUID: value}` where the value equals `user.uid`, but your security rule:

```
match /{path=**}/favorited/{userUID} {
  allow create, update, read: if request.auth.uid == userUID;
```

is specifically looking for document(s) with the *Id* of request.auth.uid.

Remembering that Security Rules are *not* filters, have you created your documents such that each document with *Id* {value} also has a *field* `{userUID: value}` ?

The *query* has to do the filtering; the Security Rule ensures that only Queries whose results *ALL* pass the rule will succeed. If the query *can* result in a whose Id is NOT the same as the field `{userUID: value}` it will be rejected.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Yes all my documents under subcollections with the name "favorited" has the field "{userUID: value}" and I've tried it with "request.auth.uid == resource.data.userUID" instead of "request.auth.uid == userUID" too. Is this what you meant? But it didn't work either..

Comment: No, I mean do they all have the documentID of userUID?  Your Security Rule, as written, has *nothing* to do with **ANY** field in the document; it is requiring that the documentID, itself, be equal to userUID. Match  expressions relate to the collection and document names, **NOT** fields.